# Unable to retrieve Height from a toggleClass jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function

I want to get the height of a class that is toggled. When a button is clicked, the class `.category-menu-visible` is added. If the class exists, then I want to get it's height. But when I alert `menuHeight`, it is 0.

[Small scale JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/BradMitchell/zpq2r0zr/)

Actual Code:

jQuery

```
jQuery('.topics-btn').click(function(){
  jQuery('.category-menu-wrap').toggleClass('category-menu-visible');

  if (jQuery('.category-menu-wrap').hasClass('category-menu-visible')){
    var menuHeight = jQuery('.category-menu-visible').height();
    alert(menuHeight);
    jQuery('.sidebar .content-wrap').css('margin-top', menuHeight);
  } else {
    jQuery('.sidebar .content-wrap').css('margin-top', 0);
  }

});
```

CSS:

```
.category-menu-wrap {
  width:100%;
  height:0px;
  background-color:#F7D5B6;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .5s cubic-bezier(.27,1.76,.95,1.19);
}
.category-menu-visible {
  height: 70px;
  transition: height .3s cubic-bezier(.27,1.76,.95,1.1);
}
```

Why can't it retrieve the height?

Comment: Have you tried getting the CSS value of height? `var menuHeight = jQuery('.category-menu-visible').css( "height" );`

Comment: Can you include your html? Even better if you include a jsfiddle or code snippet as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait till transition finishes.
**Update:**
There is a useful event [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) to do it:

```js
jQuery('.topics-btn').click(function(){
  var $menu = jQuery('.category-menu-wrap');
  $menu.toggleClass('category-menu-visible');
  $menu.on("transitionend", function(){
    if (jQuery('.category-menu-wrap').hasClass('category-menu-visible')){
      var menuHeight = jQuery('.category-menu-visible').height();
      alert(menuHeight);
      jQuery('.sidebar .content-wrap').css('margin-top', menuHeight);
    } else {
      jQuery('.sidebar .content-wrap').css('margin-top', 0);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.category-menu-wrap {
  height: 0;
}
.category-menu-visible {
  height: 70px;
  transition: height .3s cubic-bezier(.27,1.76,.95,1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<button class='topics-btn'>Click</button>
<div class='category-menu-wrap'></div>
```

Comment: Okay seems that is the problem, I'll have to go another way about doing the transition then.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

> The value reported by .height() is not guaranteed to be accurate when the element or its parent is hidden. To get an accurate value, ensure the element is visible before using .height()

The problem here is exactly this: **your `.category-menu-visible` is not visible.** when JQuery looks for it. This is due to the transition property set with a duration on the toggled class.

---

**Update (according to JSFiddle)**

It appears that when toggling a class, the height isn't recognized on the toggled class unless a **unit of measurement** is specified.

This occurs even **without the transition property**.

[Not working example](https://jsfiddle.net/dankreiger/zpq2r0zr/3/) - `height: 70;`

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dankreiger/zpq2r0zr/2/)** - `height: 70px;`

Comment: This also didn't work. Might be important to add the height of the category-menu-wrap is set to 0.

Comment: @JamesMitchell If you run the code-snippet, it alerts `70` - could you run the snippet?

Comment: Yes, works for me in that case, but added a JSFiddle of my case. I think the issue is the other class that already exists on the item with a height of 0.

Comment: @JamesMitchell I updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dankreiger/zpq2r0zr/2/) - I found that if the toggled class has a height **with units**, JQuery's `height()` function works. Interestingly enough, if you set the height without a specified unit (i.e. `70` instead of `70px`), it doesn't work - I'm going to update my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is the **CSS transition**. When you click the height is calculated but at that moment it is 0. After the transition it will have the 70px value. You need to get the height after the transition finishes.

In this example the transition duration is set to `0s`.

```js
jQuery('.topics-btn').click(function(){
  jQuery('.category-menu-wrap').toggleClass('category-menu-visible');

  if (jQuery('.category-menu-wrap').hasClass('category-menu-visible')){
    var menuHeight = jQuery('.category-menu-visible').height();
    alert(menuHeight);
    jQuery('.sidebar .content-wrap').css('margin-top', menuHeight);
  } else {
    jQuery('.sidebar .content-wrap').css('margin-top', 0);
  }

});
```

```css
.category-menu-wrap {
  width:100%;
  height:0px;
  background-color:#F7D5B6;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0s cubic-bezier(.27,1.76,.95,1.19);
}
.category-menu-visible {
  height: 70px;
  transition: height 0s cubic-bezier(.27,1.76,.95,1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="topics-btn">.topics-btn</button>
<div class="category-menu-wrap"></div>
```

In this other example we rely on the transitionend event to get the height value:

```js
jQuery('.topics-btn').click(function(){
  jQuery('.category-menu-wrap').toggleClass('category-menu-visible');
  
});

jQuery('.category-menu-wrap').on('transitionend',function(){
  if (jQuery('.category-menu-wrap').hasClass('category-menu-visible')){
    var menuHeight = jQuery('.category-menu-visible').height();
    alert(menuHeight);
    jQuery('.sidebar .content-wrap').css('margin-top', menuHeight);
  } else {
    jQuery('.sidebar .content-wrap').css('margin-top', 0);
  }

});
```

```css
.category-menu-wrap {
  width:100%;
  height:0px;
  background-color:#F7D5B6;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s cubic-bezier(.27,1.76,.95,1.19);
}
.category-menu-visible {
  height: 70px;
  transition: height 0.5s cubic-bezier(.27,1.76,.95,1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="topics-btn">.topics-btn</button>
<div class="category-menu-wrap"></div>
```